# Passing column values from a table as parameter to a stored procedure sql

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a stored procedure that accepts two values.
The stored procedure looks like this `SP_Test(ID1,ID2)`.

I have an Oracle table T1 which has two columns ID1 and ID2. I want to read each row from this table and pass parameters(ID1 and ID2) to the stored procedure SP_Test.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks
Anusha

Comment: Anusha :  An Ideal solution would be to restructure your stored procedure so as to fetch and manipulate the rows within it (if required) rather than call it multiple times, especially if you have  several rows returned from the query. So, if you can show the part  of the procedure  or  describe how it uses the arguments id1,id2, we may be able to suggest you a better approach.

Answer (score 0):

In a loop?

```
begin
  for cur_r in (select id1, id2 from t1) loop
    sp_test (cur_r.id1, cur_r.id2);
  end loop;
end;
```

Comment: Hi This deletes only the first occurrence?

Comment: If you say so. I have no idea what your procedure does, I'm just saying how to run it for all rows stored in the T1 table.